# What is the point of `std::make_optional`

Tags: c++, c++17, stdoptional, ctad, deduction-guide

All the `std::make_` are made redundant by C++17 with the introduction of [Class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (except `make_unique` and `make_shared`).

So what is the point of [`std::make_optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/make_optional)? As far as I can tell it does the exact same thing as the [deduction guides for `std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/deduction_guides).

Is there a scenario where `std::make_optional` is preferred over deduction guides?

Comment: "*except `make_unique` and `make_shared`, they are still needed for reasons of leak free memory*" - that is not why those functions exist. They exist to create `unique_ptr`/`shared_ptr` objects *more efficiently* (especially `shared_ptr`) than creating them with raw pointers passed to their constructors.

Comment: @RemyLebeau correct, I didn't realised that with C++17 you can't have interleaved parameter evaluations so it can't leak anymore.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Leak freedom is precisely why those functions exist. If you write `void func(std::unique_ptr<int>, std::unique_ptr<int>);` and then call it `func(std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42)), std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(13));`, you can get a memory leak, because the compiler is allowed to make calls in this order: `new`, `new`, `unique_ptr ctor`, `unique_ptr ctor`. If the second `new` throws, the first allocation is leaked. If you call `func(std::make_unique<int>(42), std::make_unique<int>(13));`, the calls to `new` and the calls to the `unique_ptr` ctor can not get separated.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet since C++17 that sequence is not allowed anymore. Iirc the order of the function arguments is implementation specific, but with that order each argument evaluation is sequenced before the next.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One example of the difference is when you want (for whatever reason) to make an optional containing an optional:

```
#include <optional>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    auto inner=std::make_optional(325);
    auto opt2=std::make_optional(inner); // makes std::optional<std::optional<int>>
    auto opt3=std::optional(inner);      // just a copy of inner
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(opt2), std::optional<std::optional<int>>>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(opt3), std::optional<int>>);
}
```

Comment: It is unfortunate that the library solution is needed for generic code because the core language chose a default that is convenient for the non-generic case.

Comment: @DavisHerring you wanted `std::optional<int> a{}; auto x = std::optional{a}` to be `std::optional<std::optional<int>>` and `std:vector<int> v1{}; auto v2 = std::vector{v1}` to be `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`? And what would `std::string s1{}; auto s2 = std::string{s1}` be?

Comment: @bolov The fact that `vector{v1}` and `vector{v1, v1}` are both valid and wildly different types is, I think, a mistake. `string{s1}` isn't the same kind of thing at all, since `string` is actually a type. Bonus points for `tuple{x}` being one of three different things dependent on `x`...

Comment: @bolov Or more so that `vector{x}` is either a vector containing 1 element (`x`) or a copy of `x`, depending on `x`.

Comment: @bolov: Yes; it’s a common (though surely not universal) opinion that “wrap by default” would have been better than “copy by default” because the latter can already be written as just `auto x=a;` without harming genericity.

Comment: @bolov I was joking, I was pointing out how his code doesn't have any * or pointers of the sort and yet you still called him a three star programming ***chuckling*.

Comment: @Barry very good points. My personal peeve is list intialization having the same syntax as a constructor. But now that I think about it that would solve the vector and tuple problem, but not the optional one.

Answer (score 5):

Another example of a use for `std::make_optional()` would be for constructing the object stored in a `std::optional` without creating a temporary for it when its constructor takes multiple arguments.

For example, consider the following `Point3D` class whose constructor has multiple arguments:

```
struct Point3D {
   Point3D(int xx, int yy, int zz): x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) {}
   int x, y, z;
};
```

Imagine that you want to initialize the object stored by a `std::optional<Point3D>` to `Point3D(1, 2, 3)`<sup>X</sup>, then you could proceed as:

```
std::optional oPoint = Point3D(1, 2, 3);
```

However, this would create a `Point3D` temporary object that is then moved into the `std::optional`. Instead, by using the `std::make_optional()` convenience function template you can avoid the creation of that temporary:

```
auto oPoint = std::make_optional<Point3D>(1, 2, 3);
```

Since we are talking about C++17 here (i.e., `std::optional` was introduced in C++17), *guaranteed copy elision* applies here, and therefore no `Point3D` temporary object is created.

---

Note that you can still avoid the creation of the temporary object without using `std::make_optional()` by passing `std::in_place` to the constructor of the `std::optional<Point3D>` object:

```
std::optional<Point3D> oPoint{std::in_place, 1, 2, 3};
```

This will construct the stored `Point3D` object *in place*, thus avoiding the creation of a temporary. Nevertheless, you may find this more verbose than the approach with `std::make_optional()`.

---

<sup>X</sup>`std::optional<Point3D> oPoint(1, 2, 3);` doesn't compile.

Comment: "when its constructor takes multiple arguments"... how would this be different if the constructor took a single argument?

Comment: @DavidFaure In that case you can simply pass the single argument the constructor takes directly to `std::optional`'s constructor. For example, for `struct Foo{ Foo(int){} };`, you can just construct a `std::option<Foo>` with `std::optional<Foo> optFoo(7);`. Note that this wouldn't compile if `Foo`'s constructor took multiple arguments as `std::in_place` would need to be passed to `std::option<Foo>`'s constructor.